# jquery Chosen scripts not loading when using relative path

Tags: javascript, html, path

i'm testing the chosen scripts for my web page but i don't see why it fails to load them. if put the html test file in the same level where the scripts are they works just fine, but if put the scripts in the folder  where i put all the javascript files the page stop working

the working html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='chosen.jquery.min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="chosen.min.css" />
</head>
<body>

<h2>Chosen Plugin Demo :</h2>

<select name=animals id=sl_anim style="width:300px;">
      <option value=""></option>
            <option>American Black Bear</option>
            <option>Asiatic Black Bear</option>
            <option>Brown Bear</option>
            <option>Giant Panda</option>
            <option selected>Sloth Bear</option>
            <option disabled>Sun Bear</option>
            <option selected>Polar Bear</option>
            <option disabled>Spectacled Bear</option>
</select>


<script>
    $('#sl_anim').chosen();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

not working:

```
<script src='/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/chosen/chosen.min.css" />
```

both files are the same  except on the loading script code.
i have tried:

```
 <script src='./chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js'></script>
 <script src='../chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js'></script>
```

i just i don't know how to fix this, temporary i'm writing the code within the working html file. Why others js files load fine but those two don't? How to fix this?

Comment: I don't see the JavaScript folder name in your paths at all.

Comment: @isherwood for the test i put the wroking html inside the chosen folder where all chosen scripts are and one outside of this folder, that's why the .../chosen/...